# How to use Jenkins declarative pipeline to build and test on multiple platforms

Tags: jenkins, cmake, jenkins-pipeline, googletest, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to do something that I feel should be simple to do, but I can't figure out how.

Basically I have a Jenkins master (running on Linux) and two slaves, one on Windows and the other on macOS.

I want to build my project on all 3 platforms and run GTest tests on all 3 platforms too.

I can build and run the test, but the junit step doesn't seem to collect any test results.

I tried to put the `post` block everywhere, but it just doesn't work. If I try to put the `post` block in the Test stage or as a sibling of `stages`, I get the following error:

`Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node`

which is caused by `agent none` - the `post` block doesn't know where to run.

So I tried to put the `post` block inside the `node` block in my `parallel` step for the Test stage, but it doesn't seem to do anything - it doesn't even show up in the console output.

Here's my `Jenkinsfile`:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage ('Clean') {
            steps {
                parallel (
                    "linux" : {
                        node ("linux") {
                            dir("build") {
                                deleteDir()
                                writeFile file:'dummy', text:'' // Creates the directory
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "windows" : {
                        node('windows') {
                            dir("build") {
                                deleteDir()
                                writeFile file:'dummy', text:'' // Creates the directory
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "mac" : {
                        node('mac') {
                            dir("build") {
                                deleteDir()
                                writeFile file:'dummy', text:''  // Creates the directory
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }

        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                parallel (
                    "linux" : {
                        node ("linux") {
                            checkout scm
                            dir("build") {
                                sh '/opt/cmake/bin/cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
                                sh 'make'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "windows" : {
                        node('windows') {
                            checkout(changelog: false, scm: scm) // Changelog to false, otherwise Jenkins shows duplicates. Only linux (the Jenkins master) has the changelog enabled.
                            dir("build") {
                                bat 'cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Qt/5.9.1/msvc2017_64'
                                bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild'}\" project.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=\"x64\" /p:ProductVersion=1.0.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER} /m"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "mac" : {
                        node('mac') {
                            checkout(changelog: false, scm: scm) // Changelog to false, otherwise Jenkins shows duplicates. Only linux (the Jenkins master) has the changelog enabled.
                            dir("build") {
                                sh 'cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
                                sh 'make'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }

        stage ('Test') {
            steps {
                parallel (
                    "linux" : {
                        node ("linux") {
                            dir('Build') {
                                sh './bin/project-tests --gtest_output=xml:project-tests-results.xml'
                                // Add other test executables here.
                            }

                            post {
                                always {
                                    junit '*-tests-results.xml'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "windows" : {
                        node('windows') {
                            dir("build") {
                                bat 'tests\\project\\Release\\project-tests --gtest_output=xml:project-tests-results.xml'
                                // Add other test executables here.
                            }

                            post {
                                always {
                                    junit '*-tests-results.xml'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "mac" : {
                        node('mac') {
                            dir("build") {
                                sh './bin/project-tests --gtest_output=xml:project-tests-results.xml'
                                // Add other test executables here.
                            }
                            post {
                                always {
                                    junit '*-tests-results.xml'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just some piece of general advice: *Make it smaller*. Drop platforms except one, drop stages, put everything into one step - do whatever is necessary to actually _see it working_. Then, re-add stuff of the original pipeline; hopefully, you see exactly where it breaks down.

Comment: Don't record in post build steps when you have multiple nodes and parallel. Publish test reports as a step in each node after build command executed. For ref: https://github.com/jenkins-infra/pipeline-library/blob/master/vars/buildPlugin.groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `post{}` block should only follow `steps{}` or `parallel{}` (for parallel stages) to take effect.
2. If you require post to be executed in a node environment, you should provide a node to the entire stage (`agent{}` statement).

You could try to use parallel stages execution. Also I'd suggest to use functions to shorten the code.

Something like this:

```groovy
void Clean() {
    dir("build") {
        deleteDir()
        writeFile file:'dummy', text:'' // Creates the directory
    }
}

void SmthElse(def optionalParams) {
    // some actions here
}

pipeline {
    agent none
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout(true)   // to avoid force checkouts on every node in a first stage
        disableConcurrentBuilds()   // to avoid concurrent builds on same nodes
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clean') {
            failfast false
            parallel {
                    stage('Linux') {
                        agent {label 'linux'}
                        steps {Clean()}
                        post {
                            // post statements for 'linux' node
                            SmthElse(someParameter)
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Windows') {
                        agent {label 'windows'}
                        steps {Clean()}
                        post {
                            // post statements for 'windows' node
                        }
                    }
                    stage('MacOS') {
                        agent {label 'mac'}
                        steps {Clean()}
                        post {
                            // post statements for 'mac' node
                        }
                    }
            }
            post {
                // Post statements OUTSIDE of nodes (i.e. send e-mail of a stage completion)
            }
        }

        // other stages (Build/Test/Etc.)
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use `node` in post statements:

```groovy
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        // your parallel Test steps
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                parallel (
                    "linux" : {
                        node('linux') {
                            // 'linux' node post steps
                        }
                    },
                    "windows" : {
                        node('windows') {
                            // 'windows' node post steps
                        }
                    }

                    // etc
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```